# How to write a shell script to run scripts on several remote machines without ssh?

Tags: linux, shell, amazon-ec2

Can anyone please tell me how I can write a bash shell script that executes another script on several remote machines without ssh.

The scenario is I've a couple of scripts that I should run on 100 Amazon Ec2 cloud instances. The naive approach is to write a script to scp both the source scripts to all the instances and then run them by doing a ssh on each instance. Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I mean without using ssh. You see I cannot ssh to each of the 100 remote instances to run my scripts.

Comment: Why not? It should only take a couple of minutes if serialized, even less if parallel.

Comment: can you please give more details on how to automate the process using serialization or parallel execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do stuff in parallel, you can use [Parallel SSH](http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/) or [Cluster SSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/).  If you really don't want to use SSH, you can install a task queue system like celery.  You could even go old school and just have a cron job that periodically checks a location in s3 and if the key exists, download the file and run it, though you have to be careful to only run it once.  You can also use tools like [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) and [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) if you're generally trying to manage a bunch of machines.

Comment: Well, it turned out to be easier than I anticipated. The work is done. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I do not login here that often. I decided to go with writing a script for serialized ssh although I was really tempted to go for parallel ssh. Thank for your answer, it was very informative :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `rsh`, but be careful, it has security implications.  See [rsh vs. ssh](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/rsh-vs-ssh-772596/).